# How to share MS Project macro?

Tags: ms-project

I have created a macro in my MS- Project. I am admin. Now how can I make it available to be used by other MS- Project users of my enterprise? Macro is created in Global file/template.

Comment: Which MS Project version are you using?

Comment: MS Project 2016

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. You can send others your global.mpt file and they can replace theirs with yours.
2. You can use the Organizer to copy the module into a blank project file and send that out to your team. They would then use the Organizer to copy the module into their global.mpt file. This is likely the better way so that each user's global file, with their own macros, customizations, etc. is not replaced with yours.

The Organizer is located under the File tab of the Ribbon.

Here is [Microsoft's documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-reports-calendars-and-views-in-project-78d9c687-b70f-4a20-86c5-e1c65c124261).
Here is a better [overview of the Organizer](https://www.teachucomp.com/the-organizer-in-microsoft-project-instructions/).

Comment: Hi Rachel. I have worked out through that. I created the macros in 'Enterpise Global template'. And that way, macros are enabled in every user's computer every time they open a project with 'Enabling' macros. Thank you so much. This way there is no dependency on each user as they don't have got to do any work with macros.

Comment: However, now I am stuncking at, how do I create a button in everybody's mpp(Project) using which they can run that macro. Likewise I can create a button in my system and use that. How to do that at enterprise level.

Comment: This should help: [How to: Use VBA to Add a Custom Command to the Ribbon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee767705(v=office.14)).